# Integrate TabNavigator bar into StackNavigator header in React navigation

Tags: android, react-native, tabbar, react-navigation

I would like to have `TabNavigator` bar under the `StackNavigator` header like in android settings...

[image]

So I put `TabNavigator` inside `StackNavigator` and the result is annoying elevation of `StackNavigator` header...

[image]

**Does anybody know how to get rid of that elevation without affecting ios side?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in setting of `StackNavigator` style. See `elevation` property. But it is working only up to `react-navigation` version `1.0.0-beta.7`

```
StackNavigator.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Blabla',
  header: {
    tintColor: Colors.navbarTintColor,
    style: {
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.surfacePrimary,
    },
    right: this.renderContexMenu(),
  },
}
```

Late versions uses `headerStyle` instead `header`